# R will not read shapefile / file.exists returns true

Tags: shapefile, r, error

I cannot successfully read a shapefile in R.

I'm using Rstudio version 0.99.902

I have read several articles on readOGR errors that concern reading a shapefile.

My shapefile is error free, as it opens in qGIS. when I check prescence of file, file.exists returns TRUE yet I get a "Cannot open layer" error:

> > Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = >>use_iconv, : Cannot open layer

Any advice?

Comment: Does your file path for dsn have a "/" at then end? Remove it

Comment: the dsn does *not* have a "/"    still doesn't work!   very frustrating

Comment: Have you tried with other packages to read a shapefile ?

Comment: what package do you recommend as next best option? thanks!

Comment: maptools, shapefiles - both on CRAN, s-u/fastshp and thk686/rgdal2 -   both on Github. Everything else uses rgdal, afaik.

Comment: Please click 'edit' and add your code!

Comment: Can you provide more documentation, in the form of your actual readOGR()  call? And maybe the paths of your files.

Comment: Fwiw just use raster:: shapefile to replace readOGR and writeOGR for this format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took me a bit to get this too.

```
# shapefile path example:
# C:/Users/User/GIS/MyShapefile.shp

# OGR command:
library(rgdal)
readOGR("C:/Users/User/GIS", "MyShapefile")
```

You have to leave off the ".shp" extension as well as the last forward slash on the path.

Comment: I wonder if the errors output of readOGR could be modified to flag this issue specifically??

Comment: Or modified to fix the input. I wonder in what proportion users use the various file formats available to ogr. The input schema makes sense but is confusing coming from desktop GIS software.

Comment: Looks like the new version of rgdal does what you want. I can call a shapefile by it's full .shp path and it loads fine. I did it by accident and it works!

Comment: @JMT_2080AD  Can you share your code?  Still struggling with readOGR   Thanks!  :)

Comment: @Ben send me what you have here and I'll show you what you are doing wrong. As a note, if you update your R instance with the new rgdal library you should be able to load the "xxx.shp" with extension directly.

Comment: Thanks @JMT_2080AD   let me research the issue and get you something as reproducible as possible

Answer (score 1):

I also received this error message when reading in a shapefile in QGIS (3.4.3 using the R "Autocor spatiale" tool. Tried running it in R (3.5.2) and had the same issue.

It took me a while to figure this silly one out, but I had my shapefile on a USB (moving between a Mac and PC to make sure a module works for students using both types of OS). Once I migrated the shapefile to my hard disk, it worked.